# android.support.v4.app.Fragment disadvantages

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

Before changing my entire app to v4 fragments, can someone tell me if there're important disadvantages I should take under consideration? What are the differences between the original fragment and the v4 one?

Comment: Support library was introduced for backward compatibility. Fragments was introduced from Android 3.0+ else there is no difference between them. To use fragment below android 3.0 we use support v4

Comment: Fragment starts from Android 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no obvious disadvantages to use support library to develop android app. Conversely, there might be some problem if you don't use support library in your android app.

The official [document](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) suggest we should consider to use support library for best practices when develop our android app. We can improve the app performance, UI and backward compatibility when using the features provided in support library.

Answer (score 0):

This library used to write apps that run on platforms prior to Android 3.0 , Also when running on Android 3.0 or above, this implementation is still used.
The main differences when using this support version instead of the framework fragment version are:

-Your activity must extend FragmentActivity
-You must call getSupportFragmentManager() to get the FragmentManager